# Как вывести последние посты из данных категорий?

Tags: sql, mysql

В общем, такая проблема: есть таблица с постами, есть таблица с категориями. Выполняю запрос, чтобы получить последние посты из категорий номер 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 за прошедшее время. Но не выходит - появляются только самые-самые первые посты из данных категорий.

```
SELECT date, p.cat_id, title, cat_name, cat_runame, cat_slug
FROM post AS p JOIN category AS c ON p.cat_id=c.cat_id
WHERE p.cat_id IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')
AND date < NOW()
GROUP BY cat_id
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Как исправить сложившуюся ситуацию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все, получилось. Вложил эту таблицу только без 3-ей строчки (обозначу ~) в новую. Но это не лучший способ наверное. Хотя бы потому что тут два ORDER BY теперь. Жду еще вариантов =)

SELECT *
FROM (~) AS orig
WHERE p.cat_id IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')
ORDER BY date DESC